# Expo "Something went wrong", app does not load (connectivity is not the problem!)

Tags: react-native, expo

First things first:
This is not an issue that has to do with network connectictivity or network adapter priorities.
From my phone I can connect to all oft the three ports (1900[0,1,2]) that the expo bundler exposes, so the network connection is there.

Nonetheless, after scanning the QR code I get the dreaded "Something went wrong.". In the console I even get a hint (Warning: This project conaints unoptimized assets....) which means that something is definitely going on. 
The error just says "Uncaught Error: Could not load ..."

FWIW: The same happens when running in the Android Emulator on the same machine, also when using the "local" connection.

Comment: You should see error in console, or in Debugging page which opens automatically, or from console

Comment: Yes, as noted above it say's: "Uncaught Error: Could not load ...."